# Why we need stdin as the file version of the input functions?

Tags: c

In C, *stdin* is a valid file pointer, thus we could use *stdin* (and the 2 others) with the "file" version of the input functions if we want or need to.

Why might us need to (Rather than just pipe in from shell)? Could anyone come up with some examples please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an example:

```
FILE * input = argc == 2 ? fopen(argv[1], "r") : stdin;

fgets(buf, sizeof buf, input);
```

Now you can use your tool as `magic data.txt` and as `magic < data.txt`.

Comment: One of those rare times that I understand the answer and don't understand the question :)

Comment: @zubergu: I think the OP is asking why `stdin` is defined and exists. In her mind, someone who wants to read from the standard input should be using `scanf` and not `fscanf(stdin, ...)`.

Answer (score 1):

If you write a function that works on any `FILE *`, and at a higher level you decide that you want the output to go to `stdout`.  Or read from any `FILE *` and instead you decide to read from `stdin`.

If you at, for example, the program `wc` which counts characters in a file, you'll see that it can read from `stdin` or from a file name given as a command line argument.  This decision could be made in the `main` by checking to see if the user provided a file name with `$ wc file.txt` or called with just `wc`, or piped input from something else `$ ls -l | wc`

```
$ wc # reads from stdin
$ wc file.txt # counts characters in file.txt
$ ls -l | wc # reads from stdin also.
```

and you can imagine a simple main which says:

```
int count_chars(FILE *in);

int main(int argc, char *argv) {
    if (argc == 2) {  // if there is a command line argument
        FILE *input = fopen(argv[1], "r");  // open that file 
        count_chars(input);   // count from that file
    } else {
        count_chars(stdin);   // if not, count from stdin
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Additionally to print errors one would use `fprintf(stderr, "an error occured\n");`